# Optimize Join Query All left rows and join bit indicator

Tags: sql, oracle, join

So I have this 3 tables:

**T1**

```
T1
--
ID
--
1
2
3
4
5
```

**T2**

```
T2
--
ID
--
1
2
3
```

**T1_2 that connects (N-N) T1 with T2**

```
T1_2
-----------
ID_T1|ID_T2
-----|-----
1    |2
3    |2
```

And I would like to get the following result

```
EXPECETED RESULT
-----------------
IS_CONNECTED|ID_T1
-----------------
1          |1
0          |2
1          |3
0          |4
0          |5
```

I come to this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN T1.ID=T1_2.ID_T1 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) IS_CONNECTED,
  T1_2.ID_T1
FROM T1,T1_2
GROUP BY T1_2.ID_T1
;
```

But it looks pretty ugly, and I think there must be a prettier, more optimized of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
select t1.id, decode(id_t1, null, 0,1) IS_CONNECTED 
from t1, t1_2 where t1.id  =id_t1 (+)
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to write this query is:

```
SELECT T1.ID, COUNT(T2.ID_T1) as IS_CONNECTED,
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     T1_2
     ON T1.ID = T1_2.ID_T1
GROUP BY T1.ID;
```

Notes:

- This uses proper, ANSI `JOIN` syntax.
- This does not use the Oracle-specific `DECODE()` function.
- Instead, this uses `COUNT()`, which is simpler to write and easier to understand.